# C MPI : where are my numbers - generate and print matrix

Tags: c, mpi

I try to generate a `n * n` matrix with some numbers on it. The matrix is generated in an MPI script, so basically each rank shall generate its own part of the matrix. Thus, my `n` is the dimension of the matrix, `startrow`, where a current rank should start generating numbers and `numrows`, the size of rank's workload.

```
double* generateMatrix(int n, int startrow, int numrows) {
    double* A;
    int i;
    int diag;

    A = (double*)calloc(n * numrows, sizeof(double));

    for (i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
        diag = startrow + i;

        A[i * n + diag] = n;
        
        printf("we inserted in %i the number %i\n", i*n+diag, n);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n * numrows; ++i) printf("%d ", A[i]);

    return A;
}
```

Now I would imagine, that the print outs should match, order aside. But I get the following output. So now I wonder - where are the numbers?

```
we inserted in 8 the number 16
we inserted in 25 the number 16
we inserted in 42 the number 16
we inserted in 59 the number 16
we inserted in 12 the number 16
we inserted in 29 the number 16
we inserted in 46 the number 16
we inserted in 63 the number 16
we inserted in 0 the number 16
we inserted in 17 the number 16
we inserted in 34 the number 16
we inserted in 51 the number 16
we inserted in 4 the number 16
we inserted in 21 the number 16
we inserted in 38 the number 16
we inserted in 55 the number 16

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: You allocated and wrote `double` values, but are reporting `double` with `%d`. Please enable compiler warnings.